# How to make sure the process signalled to terminate using TerminateProcess WinAPI is actually terminated?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, terminate, waitforsingleobject

I am writing the following code to terminate a process with the given PID:

```
int TerminateProcessInstance(DWORD dwPID)
{
 HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPID);
 if (!TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0))
 {
  cout << "Failed to initiate terminate process" << endl;
  return -1;
 }
 else
 {
  // Now that the termination of process is initiated,
  // how do I confirm the process is terminated before proceeding here
 }
 CloseHandle(hProcess);
 return 0;
}
```

The [TerminateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess#remarks) API documentation mentions to use [WaitForSingleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) to make sure the process has terminated:

> TerminateProcess is asynchronous; it initiates termination and returns immediately. If you need to be sure the process has terminated, call the WaitForSingleObject function with a handle to the process.

---

Should I update the code like this?

```
int TerminateProcessInstance(DWORD dwPID)
{
 HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPID);
 if (!TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0))
 {
  cout << "Failed to initiate terminate process" << endl;
  return -1;
 }
 else
 {
  bool bStatus = WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 60000);
  if(bStatus == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
  {
   cout << "Failed to terminate process" << endl;
   return -1;
  }
 }
 CloseHandle(hProcess);
 return 0;
}
```

---

Another question that I have is, if TerminateProcess did succeed in terminating the process before I call WaitForSingleObject, what will be the state of the handle hProcess?

Will WaitForSingleObject fail in that case?

Comment: Kernel objects are reference counted. As long as you hold a process handle (`hProcess`) you can use it. The call to `WaitForSingleObject` is safe regardless of whether the process has terminated. The system doesn't destroy the process object until the final handle to it is closed.

Comment: okay, so is using WaitForSingelObject using the process handle the correct way to confirm the process is terminated?

Comment: If you're still worried about it, after `WaitForSingleObject` you can use `GetExitCodeProcess` to retrieves the termination status of the specified process: `GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &dWResult)`. Before it you need to set a pointer to a variable to receive the process termination status: `DWORD dWResult`. Then check the return value of `GetExitCodeProcess` .

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject` is the way to go.  We have a task manager in our suite that uses it when shutting down our system.  We send an exit message and wait. If the wait times out, then our task manager attempts to kill the process using terminate and waits again before moving on. We must reboot if the kill fails, but only after everything that will exit has exited. The wait allows our shutdown to operate at maximum speed.

Comment: Side notes: `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is too many rights to request just to call `TerminateProcess()`. You only need `PROCESS_TERMINATE`. Don't ask for more rights than you actually need. You are also not checking if `OpenProcess()` fails, and you are leaking the `HANDLE` if `OpenProcess()` succeeds but `WaitForSingleObject()` times out. Also, you should set the wait timeout to  `INFINITE` instead of 60s.

Comment: Yes I have added those checks on my actual code. For the sake of simplicity I skipped them on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling one of the (object) [wait functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/wait-functions) on a process handle is a well-defined operation that can determine whether a process has terminated.

This is easy-to-follow advice. To understand why this is true, we need to cover several concepts and introduce supporting terminology along the way.

---

At a fundamental level, a *process* is a container that holds resources. The *object* representing a process is data. Data doesn't execute.

The unit of execution is a [*thread*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)). Every thread is owned by a process. When we colloquially say that "a process executes," what we mean instead is that "one or more threads owned by a process are eligible to run."

This may not appear to be a useful distinction to make until we look at process *termination*. A call to [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) walks across all threads stored in a process object and terminates each one in turn. The process object itself remains alive.

---

With the core primitives covered in broad strokes, the previous paragraph left off with a question: If `TerminateProcess` doesn't destroy the process object, who does, and when?

(Kernel) object lifetimes are the responsibility of the [*object manager*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/windows-kernel-mode-object-manager). It maintains a reference count for each object, incrementing it as it hands out `HANDLE`s to clients, and decrementing it whenever clients relinquish their (shared) ownership with a call to [`CloseHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle).

The referenced object is destroyed only after its final `HANDLE` has been released. A successful call to `OpenProcess` thus keeps the process object alive at least until that `HANDLE` is passed into `CloseHandle`.

---

The final part revolves around the [synchronization API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/). Wait functions (such as [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject)) return whenever the object is signaled or the timeout expired, whichever happened first. Process objects transition to (and remain in) the signaled state when the process terminates, out of free will or by force.

---

In summary:

- A successful call to `OpenProcess` grants you control over the process object's lifetime
- `TerminateProcess` doesn't destroy the process object
- A wait function can reliably wait for process termination on a valid process handle

The proposed code is still wrong for several reasons:

- It requests more privileges (`PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`) than it needs (`PROCESS_TERMINATE | SYNCHRONIZE`)
- It doesn't check for errors when calling `OpenProcess`
- It coerces the return value of `WaitForSingleObject` into a `bool`
- It leaks the process `HANDLE` on several error exits

A better implementation would read like this:

```cpp
int TerminateProcessInstance(DWORD dwPID) {
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE | SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, dwPID);
    if (hProcess == NULL) return -1;

    if (!TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0)) {
        cout << "Failed to initiate terminate process" << endl;
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD res = WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 60000);
    if(res != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        cout << "Process didn't terminate within timeout" << endl;
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return -1;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 0;
}
```

Use of the [Windows Implementation Library](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) would make this code shorter, far more readable, maintainable, and robust.